# How to redirect a user to Auth Dialog?

Tags: redirect, facebook-php-sdk, user-permissions

I followed the steps [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth)

And my application doesn't redirect the user

```
$app_id = APP_ID;
$canvas_page = APP_LINK;

$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,read_stream";

echo "<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>";
```

PS: I was successful in redirecting the user with `<fb:redirect>` but since FBML will not be supported in some months, I want to find another way and "top.location.href" should be works :(

Comment: You are missing an = after client_id in the URL string.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need a semicolon to get the code to execute.  Also, the equals sign is necessary.  (Thanks [David Barker](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users/1010632/david-barker))

```
$app_id = APP_ID;
$canvas_page = APP_LINK;

$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=". $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,read_stream";

echo "<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "';</script>";
```

What do you get when you do this:`echo "<script> alert('".$auth_url."');</script>";`?

Also, and easier way to do this in PHP is like this:

```
$app_id = APP_ID;
$canvas_page = APP_LINK;

$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id". $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,read_stream";

echo <<<EOT
  <script>
    top.location.href="$auth_url";

    //checking the value of auth_url to see if that is the reason redirect is not happening.
    if (window.console) { 
        console.log("$auth_url"); 
      } else { 
        alert("$auth_url"); 
      }
  </script>
EOT;
```

Using heredoc syntax you will not have to escape anything, you can use single and doublequotes within, and variables are intrinsically replaced in your string. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But any of these solutions works for me :(

In the Javascript log I get "Erreur : a93039401447_top is not defined". I don't understand why Facebook replace "top.location.href" by "a93039401447_top.location.href"...

PS: I'm in a facebook application

Comment: In fact, in my case (application with FBML/FBJS), Facebook replace all "standard" javascript by his own.
And I think there is no equivalent to redirect people.. (not allowed..)

Comment: as long as your first page isn't a redirection in and of itself (as in a 301 redirect) you should be good. The recommended way to pull up the auth dialog/get and auth token is to do the top.location.href javascript redirect.  Might there be another problem with your code?

Comment: In fact, this works if I change the application's type (in app settings) from "FBML" to "iframe".
But if my app is "FBML", the javascript is rewrited by Facebook and I can't use this redirection. I think this is why they create the <fb:redirect> (for fbml app). So for the moment I will keep the <fb:redirect>, and, some days, I'll switch to iframe app. Thanks for help.

Comment: Sure, my pleasure.  You should know that they will deprecate FBML soon and your app may not work much longer.  ;)

Cheers and Happy Coding!